# How to make dynamic php divs for content instead of hard coding html

Tags: php

I have written from a tutorial, the code below which gets the content from a table in the db but the divs that the content are in are hard coded into the html file.

How can I turn this code into something that will create as many divs as necessary depending on the quantity of the content.
I mean, the code below separates the content in to 10 rows per div and then creates the next div.  I want to keep this structure but have the code created dynamically so that if there are 22 rows in the db then it will need to produce 3 divs, if there are 50 rows it will need 5 divs etc etc.  For each div it needs to not repeat the same 10 but start from the next row for each div.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

```
<div class="down_col">
            <?php
              $startAt = empty($_GET['startAt']) ? 0 : $_GET['startAt'];
              require_once 'functions.php';
              printDownTrans($startAt, 10);
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="down_col">
            <?php
              require_once 'functions.php';
              printDownTrans($startAt + 10, 10);
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="down_col">
            <?php
              require_once 'functions.php';
              printDownTrans($startAt + 20, 10);
            ?>
        </div>
```

**EDIT**

This is the main part of the functions.php which retreive the data from db and concat some data together:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno($link)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit(0);
}

// Retrieve the rows from sampleTable table.
$query = "SELECT * FROM sampleTable ORDER BY Data1, Data2 LIMIT $startAt,$amount";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

        $data1Data2 = $row[1] .  ' - ' . $row[2];
        echo '<p><a href="sample/sample/' . $data1Data2 . '.pdf" target="_self">' . $data1Data2 . '</a></p>';
```

Hope this helps to understand.  Thanks

Comment: Do you know how many rows you have?

Comment: no, thats the problem, the functions.php gets all of the data from the db, I just need a way of breaking it up and having it create the correct number of div's.
On a weekly basis the number of rows will increase by an unknown number and I cant keep going back in and writing more code.

Comment: What will `printDownTrans()` return for invalid input (e.g. start > #rows)?

Comment: You just need to add an outside loop. Also you `require_once` the same file over and over.

Comment: @kingkero Sorry, Im not sure what you mean?  How will there be any invalid input?  Thanks

Comment: Say you have 100 rows and call `printDownTrans(110, 10)`

Comment: @RobbieP14383 you need to know how many rows you have so know how many divs to make. ie: `ceil($numRows / 10)`

Comment: @kingkero Isnt there a way of having the php obtain the number of rows and then call the right amount?  Thanks

Comment: @FritsvanCampen, thanks I just need to find out how to code getting the total number of rows.

Comment: @RobbieP14383 show us how you're getting the data then. The bit of code you posted is useless.

Comment: There probably is. You provide too little code, to really be constructive here instead of guessing, how does `printDownTrans()` look like?

Comment: Sorry, guys, I shall up date the question above with some additional code I use now . . .

Comment: I have updated my question above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest rewriting (at least) that part of the code as I believe (database) logic and output should be separated.

However, in your code it is not separated, so why even separate the div from it? If you wouldn't, the database logic inside the function can easily be used to achieve what you want.

```
// new function parameters:
// $maxCols     maximum number of divs      default=NULL
// $colSize     how many rows in one col    default=10

if ($maxCols !== NULL)
    $limit = ','.$maxCols * $colSize;
else
    $limit = '';

$query = "SELECT * FROM sampleTable ORDER BY Data1, Data2 LIMIT ".$startAt.$limit;
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    $currentRow = 1;
    echo '<div class="down_col">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        if ($currentRow % $colSize == 0)
            echo '</div><div class="down_col">';

        $data1Data2 = $row[1] .  ' - ' . $row[2];
        echo '<p><a href="sample/sample/' . $data1Data2 . '.pdf" target="_self">' . $data1Data2 . '</a></p>';

        $currentRow++;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Now you can simply call the function once like this

```
$startAt = empty($_GET['startAt']) ? 0 : intval($_GET['startAt']);

// version 1: print all rows in cols of size 10
printDownTrans($startAt); 
// version 2: print maximum of 3 cols of size 10
printDownTrans($startAt, 3);
// version 3: print maximum of 5 cols of size 8
printDownTrans($startAt, 5, 8);
```

You can never trust user input! Especially when you are working with a database, this is a great vulnerability. When set, `$_GET['startAt']` will be used in the query with no escaping whatsoever (maybe in the parts you didn't post?) - `intval` is the easy solution here, since you always expect an integer.

Since you are new to PHP, you might not know the [modulo operator `%`](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.arithmetic.php). I hope this example helps:

```
(1 % 10 == 0)  -> (1 == 0) -> false
(4 % 10 == 0)  -> (4 == 0) -> false
(10 % 10 == 0) -> (0 == 0) -> TRUE
(11 % 10 == 0) -> (1 == 0) -> false
(20 % 10 == 0) -> (0 == 0) -> TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You said the code you post is not from yours, isn't? Anyway, answering your question, I would do as follows:

1. Execute the query to database to get all the rows.
2. Inside the while loop, store the rows in a multidimensional array, which has the structure you want to print after: you will have two counters (one for the rows and one for the groups), when the rows counter reaches 10, you increase the groups counter and reset the rows counter to zero.
3. Do a foreach to go through the array, printing the html code.

This is a suggested structure for your array:

```
Array( group_num => Array( row_num => Array( row parameters ) ) )
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this advice, I kind of understand what you mean, in fact I do, but I do not know php enough.  Are you able to show me a working example?  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ceil](http://www.php.net/ceil) function here is your sample code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM eh_patient WHERE site_id =3 ORDER BY id_patient"; 
$result_fatch = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result_fatch);
$max = ceil($row/10);
for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
?>
    <div class="down_col">
    <?php
    $startAt = empty($_GET['startAt']) ? 0 : $_GET['startAt'];
    require_once 'functions.php';
    printDownTrans($startAt, 10);
    ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I cant see how this will save me having to write the divs manually each time though?  Thanks again

Comment: Here is a for loop which actually write the div each time depending on the sql result. please run the code then you understand

Comment: What I just realized: the usage of `$startAt` is wrong in your loop, this will always call `printDownTrans($startAt,10)` instead of `($startAt+10,10)`, `($startAt+20, 10)`, etc. Also I'd suggest using a specific field in the query instead of `*` - since you only want to count the amount of rows, you don't need all the fields